# How to delete OS X Lion installer app

Tags: macos

I re-downloaded the OS X Lion installer app to burn a DVD.  After burning the DVD I put the installer files in the trash.  Now when I try to clear the trash, I get a message basically saying I only have Read Only permissions on the file, and can't delete it.  The permissions don't appear to be editable.  How can I get rid of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried rebooting before removing it from Trash again? That helps in such cases sometimes.

If that doesn't work, try opening Terminal, and entering:

```
cd .Trash
sudo rm Install\ Mac\ OS\ X\ Lion.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also force quit (press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Escape ⎋</kbd> keys then select the application from the list) the application used to burn the Lion installer since this locked access to the file thus cannot be completely deleted.